# How to debug a stored procedure error of "Procedure or function 'X' expects parameter '@Y', which was not supplied"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My script is as below

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spSearch_Stock]
    (@KeyW varchar(50),
     @Empty int)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Empty = (SELECT COUNT(Customer) FROM tbl_Stock)

    IF @Empty > 0 
        SELECT 
            StockID, Abb, LotNo, InvoiceNo, TeaState, Customer, Broker,
            TeaGrade, Pkgs, NetWeight, TotWeight, PriceUSD, CurrencyRate,
            TotalAmtUSD, BrokerageUSD
        FROM 
            tbl_Stock
        WHERE 
            (Abb) LIKE '%'+@Keyw+'%' 
        ORDER BY 
            StockID ASC, Abb ASC
    ELSE 
        SELECT 
            'null' as StockID, 'null' as Abb, 'null' as LotNo,
            'null' as InvoiceNo, 'null' as TeaState, 'null' as Customer,
            'null' as Broker, 'null' as TeaGrade, 'null' as Pkgs,
            'null' as NetWeight, 'null' as TotWeight,
            'null' as PriceUSD, 'null' as CurrencyRate,  
            'null' as TotalAmtUSD, 'null' as BrokerageUSD
END
```

I get this error:

> Procedure or function 'spSearch_Stock' expects parameter '@Empty', which was not supplied

Comment: You might be calling your SP with out passing two parameters..

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That's product specific SQL.)

Comment: Oops @marc_s, just needed to repair the title - you took out the useful bit and left "please help me with an error" `;-)`

Comment: Since this problem is related to *calling* it you must post the code that calls it. My psychic debugging powers tells me you're using .NET, and stuffing the *name* of the procedure into `SqlCommand.Text` property, but did not set the command type to procedure. Try setting `SqlCommand.CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. Having said that, are you sure you shouldn't just be declaring @Empty as a local variable? You're initializing it as the first thing inside the procedure anyway, why do you require someone to pass you a value you are going to ignore anyway?

Comment: @halfer: I put the error into the post body - where it belongs .....

Comment: Don't `COUNT` the number of rows in a table if all you care about is the difference between 0 and (1 or more). That's what `EXISTS` is for, and it will return true as soon as it's identified a *single* valid row. `COUNT` forces the system to do more work.

Comment: @marc_s: my great apologies for labouring the point, but `An error is appearing - please help me to fix this` is a title that will attract criticism and downvotes. It basically has no content.

Comment: @halfer: agreed - but the title shouldn't contain the *whole* error message - it should be a clear and concise description of what the error is about

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure has two parameters and it seems you are not passing both..

Further I see you are setting `@Empty` in the query irrespective of value passed, so I suggest change your stored procedure like below:

```
 ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spSearch_Stock]
    (@KeyW varchar(50))
 AS
 BEGIN
     Declare @empty int

     select @empty = COUNT(Customer) FROM tbl_Stock

     -- Body of stored procedure
 END
```